# drag and dropping html element

Tags: javascript

problem is here when I drag Drag this to lokesh.exe to Lokesh.exe I am getting source id:2 but destinationid is null.
when i drag-me into box it is giving correct results like source id and destination id.
I have tried below code:

```
//html

<a draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag-id" >drag-me</a>
<table>
    <tr><td id="div1" style=" border: solid 1px; width:100px; height:100px;"  ondrop="return drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td></tr>
</table>
<table align="center" class="tabelhead" style="border-collapse: collapse;">


    <tr id="1" align="center" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="return drop(event)" class="targetdiv"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <td width="500" align="left">Lokesh.exe</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2" align="center" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="return drop(event)" class="targetdiv"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <td width="500" align="left">Drag this to lokesh.exe</td>
    </tr>
</table>

//javascript



function drag(ev)
{

ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    //console.log(ev.dataTransfer);
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    var sourceid=document.getElementById(data).id;
    alert("source id:"+sourceid);
    var destinationid=ev.target.id;
    alert("destinationid:"+destinationid);
} 

function allowDrop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: Check your browser developer tools that your php code is generating correct HTML or not.

Comment: yes it is generating.I have check with firebug and develpoper tool.

Comment: Instead of alert, try to do console of source and destination elements and double check with your html.

Comment: yes you are correct http://jsfiddle.net/ZsjA3/ please check it here dhavlcengg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want target tr id then do something like this.

```
var targetTR = ev.target.parentElement;
var targetId = targetTR.id;
```

Comment: here how to attach tr text to mouse on drag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you expect `e.target` to be the `<tr>`, but the target of the event is actually the `<td>`, which doesn't have an `id` attribute.

I've updated your JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZsjA3/2/ and added a console output to demonstrate what's happening:

```
console.log(ev.target);
```

Ensure that your debugger's console is open when you run it.
I think your best bet is to move the id to the `<td>`.

Comment: but ev.target.id also giving null.

Comment: Yes, because `ev.target` is the `<td>` which does not have an id.

Comment: please drag "Drag this to lokesh.exe" to "Lokesh.exe" and see the alert box.

Comment: yes td dont have id but tr is having id.so kindly please tell me how to here how to take tr id.thank you very much for the replay.bro.